# Attempted to access index in vector

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Here is part of a function that counts the Nyquist stability criterion. Function gives an error when vectors `re` or `im` do not have five elements:

> Attempted to access im(5); index out of bounds because numel(im)=4.
>   Error in stability (line 27)
>       tran(w) = re(1) + re(2)*w.^1 + re(3)*w.^2 + re(4)*w.^3 +
>       re(5)*w.^4 +1i*(...

I want to assign `0` to the missing elements.

```
function answear=stability(re,im)
%% Function check stability of system
%re is real part of transmitation
%im is imagine part of transmitation


%% data

for n=1:length(re)
    if(re(n) == [ ])
        re(n) = 0;
    end
end

for n=1:length(im) 
    if(im (n)== [ ])
        im(n) = 0;
    end
end

if( length(re) > length(im))
    root = length(re);
else
    root = length(im);
end

for w=1:root
    tran(w) = re(1) + re(2)*w.^1 + re(3)*w.^2 + re(4)*w.^3 + re(5)*w.^4 +1i*(...
     im(1) + im(2)*w.^1 + im(3)*w.^2 + im(4)*w.^3 +im(5)*w.^4);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to expand a vector to ensure it has at least 5 elements. Each working from a different thought but doing the same.

Most compact:

```
x = [1 2 3];
x(end+1:5) = 0;
```

Assigns zero to all elements behind the matrix till the fifth element.

However, if you already know the amount of elements, this is more compact:

```
x = [1 2 3];
if numel(x)<5
   x(5) = 0;
end
```

Note that this will automatically expand with zeros untill it has 5 elements. The advantage of these methods it that it works, regardless of the orientation of your vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pad your vector with zeros to make certain it has at least 5 elements I suggest the following:

1. Make a vecotr of 5 zeros
2. Fill the first X elements of pad with your vector (lets call it `A`)

For examples with `A` begin less than 5 and `A` being more than 5 elements:

```
A= [1 2 3]
n=5
pad = zeros(1,n)
pad(1:length(A)) = A 

clear

A = [5 6 7 8 9 4 3]
n=5
pad = zeros(1,n)
pad(1:length(A)) = A
```